# Why can't I use gem in other terminal sessions?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I've created a gem, called 'simplemvc' and installed it like this:

```
gem install simplemvc-0.0.1.gem
```

Now if I run `gem list | grep 'simplemvc'`

the output is:

```
simplemvc (0.0.1)
```

But when I open another terminal tab, and run gem list, there's no `'simplemvc'` installed.

My environment: iTerm, ZSH, OS X.

Comment: Can you close all the terminal and try there by re-opening it ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit when I close all terminal sessions and open new ones, I can't see gem installed

Comment: If you use RVM check that you working on the same ruby version that you installed the gem.